# Excel VBA I'm getting a 424 error sometimes when I select a range in Excel and attempt to paste it in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste, office-automation

Here is an abbreviated copy of the code. I put a note in by the line that sometimes will generate an error 424.

```
Sub Continue()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim SalesPer As Range
    
On Error GoTo ErrorTrap2
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Create an instance of word
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(DocDirectory & "SpartanQuote.docx", ReadOnly:=True) 'Open word file
Range("DataRange").Select
Selection.Copy
wdApp.Selection.Paste 'Sometimes I'll get error 424 on this line, but not always
'Reset variables
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("ModelSelected").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorTrap2:
MsgBox "FATAL ERROR.  Sorry.  A fatal error occured. Error number: " & Str(Err.Number)
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code creates a new instance of Word each time it is run, but never closes Word. Run repeatedly you’ll have multiple hidden instances of Word.

Comment: The scope of the Word `Application` is limited by the method, so after the method ends it should be disposed.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - The only thing that gets disposed of is the variable that points to the object. Unless the instance of the application is explicitly closed, using `Application.Quit`, it will remain running. If the code is run repeatedly Task Manager will show multiple instances of Word.  To compound things further, the code in the question only makes Word visible in the event of an error.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt this subset of the full 1000 lines of code omitted the wdApp.Visible = True that is there if the document is created successfully. Sorry for the confusion. I do want to create a new instance of Word with this macro that I control but for speed I want to keep it hidden until the end.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `Selection` object you are using the Word `Application` instance in the code:

```
wdApp.Selection.Paste 'Sometimes I'll get error 424 on this line, but not always
'Reset variables
```

Instead, you may try using the document to get the selection object or any range in the document and then try to call the `Paste` method there. See [Working with the Selection Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-the-selection-object) for possible scenarious.

Comment: `wdApp.Selection` is the only way to reference Selection as it is an Application level object. The only alternative would be to use a `Range`, which is far more efficient than selecting stuff, but this would require knowing the specific location in the document that the content is to be pasted.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the Range property in my post to get the Selection instance from a document, not Application.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for your comments and help. I should have clarified that this is a subset of about 1000 lines of code. I'm creating a new document in Word based on 50+ things that may or may not have been selected in Excel. I didn't want anyone to have to wade through that many lines but should have added a few more. Regarding using a Range within Word to paste the range that was copied from Excel, I'm always going to paste at the current location in the document. @EugeneAstafiev would I need to create a range at that location in the Word doc to follow your suggestion?

Comment: @RussVerbrugge - as the document is under the control of your code you should know where you are in the document. When the document is first opened `wdApp.Selection.Range` would typically be equivalent to `set rng = wdDoc.Range: rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart`

Comment: @TimothyRylatt when I try to use the wdApp.Selection.Range command, I get an 'Invalid use of property' error with the .Range highlighted. The other thing that is strange about this whole problem is that the code worked fine for years. Recent updates from Microsoft seem to have created the issue. However, I'm sure my code wasn't perfect anyway, but it worked. If you wouldn't mind suggesting exactly what lines to add and where, I would greatly appreciate it. Going between Excel and Word has always tasked my abilities.

Comment: @RussVerbrugge - not having the full code and related document(s) makes it difficult to help. What you need to do is figure out where the insertion point will be when you open the document, and then replace your `Selection` with code that uses the `Range` object. Examples include:   `wdDoc.Paragraphs.First.Range`, `wdDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range`,